# Как содержимое одного тэга засунуть в новый тэг php

Tags: php

Как содержимое одного тэга засунуть в новый тэг?

Например, из `<name>артем</name>` нужно получить `<имя>артем</имя>`.

Comment: Возьмите str_replace() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Имя тега сменить

Comment: Приведите кусок кода в котором это нужно сделать. Пока вопрос кажется странным и неоднозначным

Comment: <?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("gifts.xml");

foreach ($xml as $product){

     $newtag =$product->name;

     echo $newtag;


}
xml файле имеется тег <name> нужно получить его содержимое и записать в другой тег <имя>

Comment: @ganjo888 есть функции для работы с DOM http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/book.dom.php